# Change color of sections

Tags: color

I want to change the section style in my latex document, so the section text are diveded in two colors as shown in the picture. The text color should change after 3 leters from green to black. How do I do that ?[image]

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I'm using the article class

Comment: How would the colouring work with numbered/unnumbered sections? Can you provide an image that shows this (or are you only using `\section*`)?

Comment: There are no numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `titlesec` package to redefine the `\section*` headings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorthree}
\newcommand\colorthree[1]{\colorthreeX#1}
\newcommand\colorthreeX[3]{{\color{ForestGreen}#1#2#3}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section*{Education}
\blindtext
\section*{Experience}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

> [image]

If you also want a horizontal line, define `\section*` as

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorthree{#1} \hrulefill}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

The following [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch updates `\@sect` to colour the first three letters of *all* sectional titles. Spaces are gobbled, so you'll have to use `~`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox,xcolor}
\newcommand{\seccolfmt}[3]{\textcolor{green!80!black}{#1#2#3}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@sect}% <cmd>
  {#8}% <search>
  {\seccolfmt #8}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% Don't number \section, \subsection, ...

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\subsection{Experience}
\section{A~section}

\end{document}
```